# A ring is a connected set

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functions, continuity, connectedness

I not know how to prove this: For example $$A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}\mid 1 < x^2 + y^2 + z^2<2 \}$$ I know that $$\partial A=S(0,1)\cup S(0, \sqrt{2})$$ can that help me at all?

I was also thinking about making this set using a function that maps a connected set into this one, but which is continuous. Again, I think that could be done using spherical coordinates, but I do not know how to do this. If anyone knows how, what if the ring in question were ellipses, or a combination of a inner ellipse and outer sphere, or vice versa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove easily that it is path-connected. From a point $A$ to a point $B$ consider this path:

- First, the arc from $A$ to the point $C$ that is the intersection of the circle through $A$ and the radius through $B$.
- Then, append the segment $BC$ to this arc.

Both pieces are clearly in the annulus, so it is path-connected.

Comment: Bu'  haw doe ? ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $0<a<b$, $A =\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid a < \| x\|  <b \right\}$ and $B=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid 0 < \| x\|  <1 \right\}$. Function $f$ is a homeomorphism from $A$ to $B$:
$$ f(x) = \frac{ \| x\| -a}{(b-a) \| x\|}x, $$
$$ f^{-1}(y) = \frac{ \| y\|(b-a) +a}{\| y\|} y. $$
Punctured ball $B$ is connected (you can argue via [path-connectedness](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Path-connected_implies_connected), as above, but easier: if origin does not lie on the segment between the given points, we are done; if it does, choose a third point that does not lie on the segment through origin and use the two new segments created).